# Running Linux terminal commands on Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, ubuntu, tkinter, terminal

I am planning to create a GUI that needs to execute some commands on linux terminal. How can i execute Linux terminal commands on Tkinter GUI buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a function that runs Linux commands when a button is clicked.

For this, Python's in-built library `subprocess` is sufficient. The syntax is as follows in order to run a simple `ls -l` in the terminal:

```
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

For a sample `tkinter` program with usage, you'll have to wrap the `subprocess.run()` in a function. For example:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess

def run():
    subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Click to run 'ls -l'", command=run).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

To learn more about the `subprocess` module and how to capture output from the terminal: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

To execute the commands, use a python module called *subprocess*. The code is as following:

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen(["ping","-W","2","-c", "1", "192.168.1.70"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

Comment: inside the square brackets and the quotes being the terminal command.

Comment: You want to avoid bare `Popen` in situations where the more friendly high-level functions such as `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.check_output` do what you want.